# UTorrent Client Api c#

Tags: c#, utorrent

I want to use "UTorrentClientApi". see it on github:

https://github.com/latop2604/UTorrentClientApi

On github He told that if we want to get Torrent lists , we must use these 3 lines of code:

```
UTorrentClient client = new UTorrentClient("admin", "password");
var response = client.GetList();
List<Torrent> torrents = response.Result.Torrents;
```

I get this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type "system.collection.generic.IList'to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'.An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

[see my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76Oae.png)

when I use "var" I don't receive error.But I can't see the result

[See my Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiu6M.jpg)

so what can I do to solve these problems?

Comment: Don't post links to code and don't post images of code - insert relevant code directly into your question

Comment: Also what you want (and don't show in this question) is to join the elements of the list (e.g.: using [`String.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx)) instead of using `.ToString()`

Comment: add .ToList() after your Result.Torrents to convert from IList to List

Answer (score 1):

You should use :

```
 List<Torrent> torrents = response.Result.Torrents.ToList();
```

This should work just fine.